# MVC5 Model Is coming back Null in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, model, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the a single model that I am trying to pass with a couple variables inside it.

I am trying to use Html.ViewData.Model.(Variable name here). I keep getting a null exception even though I have hardset values in the model.

Any ideas

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;


namespace stuff
{
    public class BACnetModel
    {
        private string _rmNum = "Room Number";
        public string RmNum { get { return _rmNum; } set{_rmNum = value;} }

        private string _avRes = "70";
        public string AvRes { get { return _avRes; } set {_avRes = value;} }

        private string _bvRes = "T";
        public string BvRes { get { return _bvRes; } set { _bvRes = value; } }

        private string _mvRes = "O";
        public string MvRes { get { return _mvRes; } set { _mvRes = value; } }
    }
}
```

Added edited controller and view actions below. I've got the null gone by declaring the model but I still am not seeing values in my view.

Controller

```
public class PEOController : Controller
{

    //Set default values
    private string AvResult = "90";
    private string BvResult = "T";
    private string MvResult = "O";
    private string rmNum = "Room";

    // GET: PEO

    public ActionResult PEO(string BvResult, string AvResult, string MvResult, string rmNum)
    {

        var model = new BACnetModel
        {
            AvRes = AvResult,
            BvRes = BvResult,
            MvRes = MvResult,
            RmNum = rmNum
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult getRoomNumber(string roomNumber, ref uint BvInstance, ref uint AvInstance, ref uint MvInstance, out string rmNum)
    {
        switch (roomNumber)
        {
            case ("1B^1001^01"):
                rmNum = "1B^1001^01";
                BvInstance = 3000018;
                AvInstance = 3000022;
                MvInstance = 3000040;
                break;

            case ("1B^1002^01"):
                rmNum = "1B^1002^01";
                BvInstance = 3000020;
                AvInstance = 3000023;
                MvInstance = 3000042;
                break;

            default:

                break;
        }
        rmNum = "Room";

        var model = new BACnetModel
        {
            AvRes = AvResult,
            BvRes = BvResult,
            MvRes = MvResult,
            RmNum = rmNum
        };


        return View(model);
    }

}
```

View

```
@using  Stuff
@using Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities
@model BACnetModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2> Stuff(PEO)</h2>
<p>
    Stuff
</p>
<label>Select a Room: </label>
<!-- I need to add Code that will loop through the database and provide rooms.
        I will need to provide a query that will be called on page load.-->

<form action="/BACnetIntegration/getRoomNumber">
    <select id="roomList">
        <option value="1B^1001^01">1B^1001^01</option>
        <option value="1B^1002^01">1B^1002^01</option>
    </select><br/><br/>

    <fieldset id="peoFieldset">
        <legend>Room Results</legend>
        <label for="roomNumber">Room Number:</label>
        <input id="roomNumber" readonly="readonly"/>@Model.RmNum<br>
        <label for="rmSetpoint">Room Setpoint: </label>
        <input id="rmSetpoint" readonly="readonly" />@Model.AvRes<br>
        <label for="rmCode">Room Code: </label>
        <input id="rmCode" readonly="readonly" />@Model.BvRes<br>
        <label for="rmOcc">Room Occupancy: </label>
        <input id="rmOcc" readonly="readonly" />@Model.MvRes<br>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<label>Occupancy Value</label>
<select id="occValue">
    <option value="Occupied">Occupied</option>
    <option value="Unoccupied">Unoccupied</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it the following action that is returning the view?

```
// GET: CCEC
public ActionResult CCEC()
{
    return View();
}
```

If so then the model will be set to null so you will get a null reference exception.  You need to give it a blank model at least or test for null in the view.

```
// GET: CCEC
public ActionResult CCEC()
{
    return View(new BACnetModel());
}
```

Comment: Yep, just caught that. Eliminated the Null issue, now I am working on getting the data to actually show up.

I have 

<p>@Html.ViewData.Model.RmNum</p><br>
but I am not seeing the data show up.

Comment: it might be because your `getRoomNumber` method returns a `RedirectToAction`.  A `RedirectToAction` will literally return a 302 http response causing the browser to redirect and reload the "action" method.  In doing so any data is lost in the redirect because it is a completely separate http call.  I would try just `return values(rmNumber, BvResult, AvResult, MvResult);` instead of `RedirectToAction`.

Comment: I edited the view and controller and reposted above.

Comment: I was just going based on your method names above.  Basically you want the 'getRoomNumber' method to return the ViewResult.  So you need to construct you model in the 'getRoomNumber' somehow (either directly or through your 'values' function) and return view from there `return View("CCEC", model);`  I just suggested returning your 'values' method since it returned the view already.

Comment: Thanks and I thought PHP MVC was complicated :-D